# print a certain line of a file in c

Tags: c, file, printing

I am trying to print a certain line of a file in c. So far I think I am successfully reading line 8 of my text file but my question is how do I print that line using this code?

Thanks!!

this is the code so far:

```
int lineNumber = 8;

static const char filename[] = "Text.txt";

FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");

int count = 0;

if ( file != NULL )
{
    char line[256]; /* or other suitable maximum line size */
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) /* read a line */
    {
        if (count == lineNumber)
        {
            //use line or in a function return it
            //in case of a return first close the file with "fclose(file);"
        }
        else
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: Just add in a `printf("%s", line);`.

Comment: I tried that but it keeps saying that line is undefined :(

Comment: You have to print it inside the while loop.

Comment: or when I move it up in the code it print the whole text file, I only want line 8 to print

Comment: I placed it in the while loop (after the else statment but before the curly brace) but it still prints the whole text, I only want line 8

Comment: Replace "//use line or in a function return it" with `printf("%s", line);`

Answer (score 2):

This works perfectly fine.

Are you missing the main function OR is it just the code snippet you have posted ?

```
int lineNumber = 8;

static const char filename[] = "Text.txt";

int main() 
{

    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    int count = 0;

    if ( file != NULL )
    {   
        char line[256]; /* or other suitable maximum line size */
        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) /* read a line */
        {   
            if (count == lineNumber)
            {   
                //use line or in a function return it
                //            //in case of a return first close the file with "fclose(file);"
            printf("\n str %s ", line);
            fclose(file);
            return 0;

            }   
            else
            {   
                count++;
            }   
        }   
        fclose(file);
    }   
return 0;

}
```